# Find a value between spaces in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I have a string and an array:

```
var first = 'b c da e f a s';
var second = ["g","h","i","j","a"];
```

I need to find the first occurrence of "a", derived from the array as last character,  in the string, so I did:

```
var first = 'b c da e f a s';
var second = ["g","h","i","j","a"];

var myArray = second.reverse();
var arrayLength = myArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {  
    var x = first.split(myArray[i])[1];

    if (typeof x !== 'undefined'){
    alert($.trim(myArray[i] + x))
    break;

    }

}
```

This outputs `a e f` while it should be `a s`. Apparently it splits up the word `da`, But I only need it to split at a whole value, so it should skip `da` unless Im looking for the entire value `da`

[Example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex5sge0g/)

Comment: what is the output you're expecting? It's unclear

Comment: @Amit Joki The output should be "a s"

Comment: You're not splitting by spaces. You're splitting by `myArray[i]`.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Yes I was looking in to that but I cant figure it out. Should I introduce spaces to the array? (I did not succeed doing so)

Comment: I think the downvotes becuase people misread the question...

Comment: It's still unclear what this code is supposed to do. You say the output should be `a s`, but WHY?

Comment: Yep. If you want the output to be `a s`, just get the last 3 characters from the string..

Comment: @Sampath Liyanage I don't know the string and array values upfront

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers, its going to take some time to digest and figure out what works best for my script

Comment: This question is not clear at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function find_remainders(first, second) {
  var words = first.split(' '); // Split up first by spaces
  var result = '';
  for (var i = second.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Loop from the end of second until we succeed
    var search = second[i]; // Get the current element of second
    var index = words.indexOf(search); // Find that element
    if (index != -1) { // If it was found
      result = words.slice(index).join(' '); // Get it and everything after it, put back into a string
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

alert(find_remainders('b c da e f a s', ["g", "h", "i", "j", "a"])); // a s
alert(find_remainders('b c da e f q s', ["g", "h", "f", "j", "a"])); // f q s
```

Comment: Thanks but it should loop trough on to the other array value. So if "a" is not found then it should look for "j" and so on, but that's a minor adjustment I guess

Comment: Where do you say that in the question? Are you going to add more requirements when I do that?

Comment: Why would I loop in the example code? There are easier ways of getting "a" just like that

Answer (score 1):

Output is `a` and `s` as a values of the `newArray`. You can implode the `newArray` if you need the string.

Split the string by spaces. Loop through the array, and if the needle is in haystack, then slice the array from that position.

```
var needle = 'a';
var haystack = 'b c da e f a s';
var parts = haystack.split(" ");

for (i=0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] === needle) {
        var newArray = parts.slice(i);
        break;
    }
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Use `parts.offsetOf(needle)` instead of a loop?

Comment: `TypeError: parts.offsetOf is not a function` for me. Can you show me a link of the reference?

Comment: Oops, meant `indexOf`.

Comment: indexOf is not good, becase if `da` is before `a` then it will found that.

Comment: That's if you use `indexOf` on the string. I'm talking about using it on the array after you `split`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange way to go about it, but if you really need this to work, split the string on a whole-word version of each string in `second`:

```js
var first = 'b c da e f a s';
var second = ["g", "h", "i", "j", "a"];

var myArray = second.reverse();
var arrayLength = myArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  var x = first.split(new RegExp('\\b' + myArray[i] + '\\b'))[1];

  if (typeof x !== 'undefined') {
    alert($.trim(myArray[i] + x))
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I accepted Barmar answer because it looks like I can expand on it more. But I like the simple regex insert, thank you for that, did not know that +1

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as written:

```
myArray (after reverse) -> ['a', 'j', 'i', 'h', 'g']
                             0    1    2    3    4
i = 0 -> myArray[i] -> 'a'

first.split('a')[1] -> ['b c d', ' e f ', 's'][1] -> ' e f ';
                           0       1       2
alert('a' + ' e f ') -> 'a e f';
```

Then you break; and terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
var first = 'b c da e f a s';
var second = ["g","h","i","j","a"];
var searchStr = second[second.length - 1];
var firstArray = first.split(' ');
for ( var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    if ( firstArray[i] === searchStr) {
        break;
    }
}
if (i < firstArray.length) {
    alert(firstArray.splice(i).join(' '));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I accept your answer since its only code that is quite similar to mine, and the only code I can wrap my head around:)

Comment: On second thoughts I realize now this is just a simplified version of my code, it doesnt loop through the other values, thanks anyway

Comment: You should ask better questions

Comment: No just this one (maybe)